# ImportError: No module named ovirtsdk.api

Tags: python, installation, ubuntu-18.04, ovirt

I am trying to run a program backup.py from this github
The link is added below.

https://github.com/wefixit-AT/oVirtBackup/blob/master/backup.py

For that first i made a b.py containg the python as only this much

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import logging
from argparse import ArgumentParser, FileType
import ovirtsdk.api
from ovirtsdk.xml import params
from ovirtsdk.infrastructure import errors
import sys
import time
from vmtools import VMTools
from config import Config
```

When i ran `python b.py` i got error as ..

```
 python b.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "b.py", line 4, in <module>
    import ovirtsdk.api
ImportError: No module named ovirtsdk.api
```

My python version is python 2.7.
How can i get rid of this error what package should i install.
I am using ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

yum install ovirt-engine-sdk-python

Answer (score 0):

Below command helps resolve the issue:

$ pip install ovirt-engine-sdk-python==3.6.9.2